# Angular JS source Appearing in Browserify bundle Due to ui-router 1.x.x

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, browserify

I use Exposify to keep a `angular` external while using `Browserify` to run a build:

expose config:

```
{
    expose: {
        angular: "angular",
        jquery: "jQuery",
        mathjax: "MathJax"
    }
};
```

With the previous versions of `angular-ui-router`, I could require them and not have this issue. With all 1.x.x versions I start seeing `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.` in the browser console.

And if I inspect the JS bundle, Angular.JS source has been included, and therefore is running twice. Am I doing something very wrong, are angular-ui-router doing something wrong, is Exposify failing, or is this behaviour expected and I need to change my approach?

Comment: Did you tryout using https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-resolutions

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. It's not duplication, it's the fact I want to entirely exclude angular source from my bundle ideally, and I have that working, but it seems that browserify resolutions doesn't see that exposify has turned the angular dep into an external one.

Comment: Meh, I've added in that plugin because it's useful, but for other reasons. I need included ui-router as external JS file in the HTML for now, but it's a start.